# SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'pcbuild0_.user_userId' in 'field list'

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I've been fighting with this program for weeks and it's just all chasing errors around and around in circles. I'm getting a "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet" error and in the stack trace, it says that there's no such thing as a column called "pcbuild0_.user_userId" in "field list". I have no idea what "field list" is and I have entered no such column "pcbuild0_.user_userId" anywhere in anything. This happens when I try to test the getById method in the PcBuildDao.

Please let me know if I need to post any more info

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hardwareviewer</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">student</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping class="entity.PcBuild" />
        <mapping class="entity.User" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="(url I can't post here)"
      xsi:schemaLocation="(same here)">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.matc.entjava.hardwareviewer</groupId>
  <artifactId>hardwareviewer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hardwareviewer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

    <javax.version>7.0</javax.version>
    <mysql-version>8.0.16</mysql-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <log4j-version>2.10.0</log4j-version>
    <jupiter-version>5.0.0</jupiter-version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit-platform-runner-version>1.0.0</junit-platform-runner-version>
    <junit-vintage-version>4.12.0</junit-vintage-version>
    <hibernate-core-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-core-version>
    <hibernate-c3p0-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-c3p0-version>

    <javb-api.version>2.3.1</javb-api.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.19</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${jupiter-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-vintage-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-c3p0-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javb-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>hardwareviewer</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webResources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
              </resource>
            </webResources>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
              <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

PcBuildDao

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import entity.PcBuild;

public class PcBuildDao {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory();

    public PcBuild getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        PcBuild pcBuild = session.get(PcBuild.class, id);
        session.close();
        return pcBuild;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdatePcBuild(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public int insert(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        int id = 0;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = (int) session.save(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void delete(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

PcBuild POJO

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "PcBuild")
@Table(name = "computer_builds")
public class PcBuild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private int buildId;

    @Column(name = "cpu_model")
    private String cpuModel;

    @Column(name = "gpu_model")
    private String gpuModel;

    @Column(name = "cpu_cooler_model")
    private String cpuCoolerModel;

    @Column(name = "Motherboard_model")
    private String motherboardModel;

    @Column(name = "psu_model")
    private String psuModel;

    @Column(name = "case_model")
    private String caseModel;

    @Column(name = "data_storage_model")
    private String dataStorageModel;

    @Column(name = "ram_model")
    private String ramModel;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    public PcBuild() {
    }

    public PcBuild(int buildId, String cpuModel, String gpuModel,
            String cpuCoolerModel, String motherboardModel, String psuModel,
            String caseModel, String dataStorageModel, String ramModel,
            User user) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getBuildId() {
        return buildId;
    }

    public void setBuildId(int buildId) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
    }

    public String getCpuModel() {
        return cpuModel;
    }

    public void setCpuModel(String cpuModel) {
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
    }

    public String getGpuModel() {
        return gpuModel;
    }

    public void setGpuModel(String gpuModel) {
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
    }

    public String getCpuCoolerModel() {
        return cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public void setCpuCoolerModel(String cpuCoolerModel) {
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public String getMotherboardModel() {
        return motherboardModel;
    }

    public void setMotherboardModel(String motherboardModel) {
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
    }

    public String getPsuModel() {
        return psuModel;
    }

    public void setPsuModel(String psuModel) {
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
    }

    public String getCase_Model() {
        return caseModel;
    }

    public void setCase_Model(String caseModel) {
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
    }

    public String getDataStorageModel() {
        return dataStorageModel;
    }

    public void setDataStorageModel(String dataStorageModel) {
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
    }

    public String getRamModel() {
        return ramModel;
    }

    public void setRamModel(String ramModel) {
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUserId(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PcBuild{" +
                "buildId=" + buildId +
                ", cpuModel='" + cpuModel + '\'' +
                ", gpuModel='" + gpuModel + '\'' +
                ", cpuCoolerModel='" + cpuCoolerModel + '\'' +
                ", motherboardModel='" + motherboardModel + '\'' +
                ", psuModel='" + psuModel + '\'' +
                ", caseModel='" + caseModel + '\'' +
                ", dataStorageModel='" + dataStorageModel + '\'' +
                ", ramModel='" + ramModel + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User POJO

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int userId, String username, String password, Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.pcBuilds = pcBuilds;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<PcBuild> getPcBuilds() {
        return pcBuilds;
    }

    public void setPcBuilds(Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds) {
        this.pcBuilds = pcBuilds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

mySQL script I run at the start of each JUnit test

```
delete from computer_builds;

delete from users;

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (1, 'fchristian', 'student');

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (2, 'achristian', 'lollipop');

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 7 5800X3D', 'PowerColor Red Devil OC Radeon RX 6950 XT', 'Deepcool AK620', 'MSI MAG B550 Tomahawk',
        'Thermaltake Toughpower GF1 PE 850 W', 'Corsair 4000D Airflow ATX Mid Tower', 'Samsung 970 Evo Plus 2 TB NVMe SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3600 CL18', 1);

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 3 3200G', 'Gigabyte GAMING OC Radeon RX 5700 XT', 'Stock', 'Gigabyte B450M DS3H Wifi',
        'Fractal Design Ion SFX 650 W', 'Thermaltake Core G3 ATX Mid Tower', 'Teamgroup GX2 512 GB SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16', 2);
```

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query that is actually executed, in order to see where this column is used?

Also why don't you use `@JoinColumn` to give the name of the column by yourself on `@ManyToOne` relationship?

Comment: @LazarosChatzimichalakis Added the mySQL script I run before each JUnit test. Also, I wasn't aware of that annotation, so I looked into it and added it to my code and I also learned that I had some typos in my mySQL query, which I also fixed, but now I'm getting a nullPointerException. I added the changes I made in my code to the post.

Comment: Try updating to at least the latest Hibernate 5.6